# Display subdirectory name of a root directory

Tags: php

I have a files like,

```
root
   -0001
   -0002
   -0003
   -test.php
```

In that php file, i wanna to fetch a subfolder name in an array how to get that details.. if anyone have the idea about that, let me know asap

thanks for your information

Comment: you want to fetch a subfolder... is it perhaps the folder you're on? In that case ```echo __DIR__;``` should do it (since PHP 5.3), or ```echo dirname(__FILE__);``` for previous versions.

Comment: `glob` is your friend. See the [manual]http://php.net/manual/en/function.glob.php